# Change the page type to horizontal react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to write a program
When it opens, it runs horizontally,
Like game mode in games.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Expo you can try the [`expo-screen-orientation`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#screenorientationlockasyncorientationlock) library, like this:

```
async function changeScreenOrientation() {
  await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_LEFT);
}
```

If you aren't using expo, you can try the [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) library